# JavaScript day picker component

Tags: javascript, web, components

I want develope component to my Spring boot web application.
Component which let me chose day of week and hour it will look like

```
Day (Monday) Hour (comboBox with hours)
...
Day (Sunday) Hour (comboBox with hours)
```

I try to figure out what JS framework will be the best to do component like this,
I assume that result from this component should be JSON, but there is another trick I want to send result from this component along with another data from form in which thic component will be embedded.

Could any one more experience Collegue could give me some advice?

Best regards for You all! :)

Comment: Is this linked to Java ?

Comment: I'm gaining some knowledge about  jQuery UI but I don't know is it good place to start?